# Pass parameter to external application using Excel - WITHOUT VBA or macros

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

I am trying to pass a method and parameters to a program (written by me) using Excel.

for example:

`goto (45302)`

However, for various reasons, I want to be able to do it without the help of a macro.

I have found two options so far:

- URL Scheme
- DDE (but I can only do this with the help of a macro, and it shows annoying prompts)

Are there any other built-in methods Excel can use to interact simply with external programs without using macros and without enabling "Trust access to the VBA project object model"?

Comment: what is 45302, you can use offset to get the value in any cell but not the formula

Comment: `45302` is the parameter, `goto` is the method i am calling in the external program